# SQL MySQL UPDATE TABLE copy one column to other column in the same table such that nth row of first column = n+1th row of second column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Disposed.
There are three columns Serialno, Businessdate, Firstdate

I want to copy the dates of Businessdate to Firstdate in such a manner that first row of Businessdate becomes the second row of Firstdate & so on.

nth row of Businessdate = n+1 th row of Firstdate

So, this is what I have in table Disposed-

```
Serialno  BusinessOnDate  FirstDate
1         2017-04-17       NULL
2         2017-04-24       NULL
3         2017-04-03       NULL
4         2017-03-18       NULL
5         2017-03-27       NULL
6         2017-03-20       NULL
```

What I want

```
Serialno  BusinessOnDate  FirstDate
1         2017-04-17       NULL
2         2017-04-24      2017-04-17
3         2017-04-03      2017-04-24
4         2017-03-18      2017-04-03
5         2017-03-27      2017-03-18
6         2017-03-20      2017-03-27
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want to update the table.  The `serialno` seems to describe the ordering.  So, you can use`join`:

```
update t join
       t tprev
       on tprev.serialno = t.serialno - 1
    set t.firstdate = tprev.businessondate;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LAG` function. if your mysql version didn't support it, can try to use a subquery to make `LAG` function.

```
SELECT t1.Serialno,t1.BusinessOnDate,(
          SELECT BusinessOnDate 
          FROM T tt
          WHERE tt.Serialno < t1.Serialno
          order by Serialno desc
          limit 1
         ) 
FROM T t1
```

If your mysql support `lag` you can try this.

```
SELECT 
    t1.Serialno,
    t1.BusinessOnDate,
    LAG(t1.BusinessOnDate) OVER(ORDER BY Serialno) FirstDate
FROM T t1
```

if you want to update you can try `self join` with a subquery

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Serialno int,
   BusinessOnDate date,
   FirstDate date
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'2017-04-17',NULL);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,'2017-04-24',NULL);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3,'2017-04-03',NULL);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,'2017-03-18',NULL);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (5,'2017-03-27',NULL);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (6,'2017-03-20',NULL);

UPDATE T t1
JOIN (
      SELECT t1.Serialno,
         (
                  SELECT BusinessOnDate 
                  FROM T tt
                  WHERE tt.Serialno < t1.Serialno
                  order by Serialno desc
                  limit 1
         )  as 'FirstDate'
      FROM T t1
) t2 on t1.Serialno = t2.Serialno
SET t1.FirstDate = t2.FirstDate
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd348/1/0)**:

```
| Serialno | BusinessOnDate |  FirstDate |
|----------|----------------|------------|
|        1 |     2017-04-17 |     (null) |
|        2 |     2017-04-24 | 2017-04-17 |
|        3 |     2017-04-03 | 2017-04-24 |
|        4 |     2017-03-18 | 2017-04-03 |
|        5 |     2017-03-27 | 2017-03-18 |
|        6 |     2017-03-20 | 2017-03-27 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Get previous date from subquery

```
UPDATE disposed d1 SET firstdate = (SELECT MAX(businessondate) 
                                    FROM disposed d2 
                                    WHERE d2. businessondate < d1. businessondate 
                                    ORDER BY businessondate)
```